# Assertion in appcore.cpp while loading regular DLL dynamically linked to MFC

Tags: visual-c++, dll, mfc

I have inherited an application which consists of a regular DLL which is dynamically linked to MFC and which is loaded from a Windows service executable which also links dynamically to MFC. The code is being compiled using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional (old, I know...). This application has been 'working' for several years but I have found that I cannot run it as Debug build due to the following assertion in appcore.cpp:

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>   Program: C:\Projects\CMM\Debug\CMM.exe
>   File: f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\appcore.cpp
>   Line: 380
>
> For more information on how your program can cause an assertion
>   failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.
>
> (Press Retry to debug the application)

which corresponds to the following code in the `CWinApp` constructor:

```
ASSERT(AfxGetThread() == NULL);
pThreadState->m_pCurrentWinThread = this;
ASSERT(AfxGetThread() == this);
```

This occurs when loading the DLL via `LoadLibrary` and leads me to suspect that the application has worked more by luck than judgement over the years (due to `ASSERT` not being included as part of the Release build).

My (admittedly limited) understanding of MFC is that although there should generally only be a single instance of `CWinApp`, it is permissible to have an additional one in regular DLLs which link dynamically to MFC, as in this case. The code has one instance in the service executable and one in the DLL. The `CWinApp` constructor gets called three (?) times, once for some internal instance within the MFC framework, once for the instance in the service executable and once for the instance in the DLL. The first two work fine, it is the third which blows up.

All of the exported functions start with `AFX_MANAGE_STATE` (although execution never gets that far) and the pre-processor flags are, I believe, correct w.r.t. Microsoft's documentation (`_AFXDLL` for the EXE, `_AFXDLL`, `_USRDLL` and `_WINDLL` for the DLL).

I have tried using `AfxLoadLibrary` instead of `LoadLibrary` to no effect. However, if I include

```
AFX_MANAGE_STATE( AfxGetStaticModuleState() )
```

at the start of the function which calls `LoadLibrary`/`AfxLoadLibrary`, the `CWinApp` object *is* actually constructed but execution then blows up in dllmodul.cpp instead.

Can anybody shed any light on why this might be happening or what I need to do to fix it?

**EDIT**

This is the call stack when the assertion occurs:

```
mfc90d.dll!CWinApp::CWinApp(const char * lpszAppName=0x00000000)  Line 380 + 0x1c bytes C++
cimdll.dll!CCimDllApp::CCimDllApp()  Line 146 + 0x19 bytes  C++
cimdll.dll!`dynamic initializer for 'theApp''()  Line 129 + 0xd bytes   C++
msvcr90d.dll!_initterm(void (void)* * pfbegin=0x1b887c88, void (void)* * pfend=0x1b887d6c)  Line 903    C
cimdll.dll!_CRT_INIT(void * hDllHandle=0x1b770000, unsigned long dwReason=1, void * lpreserved=0x00000000)  Line 318 + 0xf bytes    C
cimdll.dll!__DllMainCRTStartup(void * hDllHandle=0x1b770000, unsigned long dwReason=1, void * lpreserved=0x00000000)  Line 540 + 0x11 bytes C
cimdll.dll!_DllMainCRTStartup(void * hDllHandle=0x1b770000, unsigned long dwReason=1, void * lpreserved=0x00000000)  Line 510 + 0x11 bytes  C
ntdll.dll!_LdrxCallInitRoutine@16()  + 0x16 bytes   
ntdll.dll!LdrpCallInitRoutine()  + 0x43 bytes   
ntdll.dll!LdrpInitializeNode()  + 0x101 bytes   
ntdll.dll!LdrpInitializeGraphRecurse()  + 0x71 bytes    
ntdll.dll!LdrpPrepareModuleForExecution()  + 0x8b bytes 
ntdll.dll!LdrpLoadDllInternal()  + 0x121 bytes  
ntdll.dll!LdrpLoadDll()  + 0x92 bytes   
ntdll.dll!_LdrLoadDll@16()  + 0xd9 bytes    
KernelBase.dll!_LoadLibraryExW@12()  + 0x138 bytes  
KernelBase.dll!_LoadLibraryExA@12()  + 0x26 bytes   
KernelBase.dll!_LoadLibraryA@4()  + 0x32 bytes  
mfc90d.dll!AfxCtxLoadLibraryA(const char * lpLibFileName=0x02a70ce0)  Line 487 + 0x74 bytes C++
mfc90d.dll!AfxLoadLibrary(const char * lpszModuleName=0x02a70ce0)  Line 193 + 0x9 bytes C++
CMM.exe!CMonDevDll::LoadDLL()  Line 207 + 0x1b bytes    C++
CMM.exe!CMonDevDll::LoadDllEntryPoints()  Line 268 + 0x8 bytes  C++
CMM.exe!CMonDevDll::Initialize(CMonDevRun * pMonDevRun=0x0019fe60)  Line 186 + 0x8 bytes    C++
CMM.exe!CCtcLinkMonDev::Initialize(CMonDevRun * pMonDevRun=0x0019fe60, CCtcRegistry & reg={...}, int nLinkId=1)  Line 546 + 0x18 bytes  C++
CMM.exe!CCtcLinkSwitchMgr::Initialize(CMonDevRun * pMonDevRun=0x0019fe60, CCtcRegistry & reg={...})  Line 188 + 0x14 bytes  C++
CMM.exe!CMonDevRun::Initialize(ATL::CStringT<char,StrTraitMFC_DLL<char,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<char> > > szServiceName="CimService")  Line 257 + 0x16 bytes    C++
CMM.exe!CMonDevService::Run()  Line 202 + 0x2d bytes    C++
CommonFilesD.dll!CCtcServiceBase::ParseStandardArgs(int argc=-1, char * * argv=0x02a51b44)  Line 278 + 0xf bytes    C++
CMM.exe!main(int argc=4, char * * argv=0x02a51b38)  Line 126 + 0x16 bytes   C++
CMM.exe!__tmainCRTStartup()  Line 586 + 0x19 bytes  C
CMM.exe!mainCRTStartup()  Line 403  C
kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()  + 0x24 bytes    
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart()  + 0x2f bytes  
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x1b bytes
```

Comment: Can you tell me theApp is member of class or extern.

Comment: @SantoshDhanawade, `theApp` is declared as a global variable, it is not a class member and there are no external references to it.

Comment: https://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/432903-assertion-cwinapp-cwinapp-afxgetthread-null

Comment: http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?479727-using-dll-assertion-failed-afxgetthread()

Comment: Hi @SantoshDhanawade, thanks for the links. I actually read the first one before posting here but it does describe the problem I am facing. Unfortunately, I am not loading the DLL from any constructors and I have not identified any mis-match in the library versions of link parameters between the executable and the DLL. The second one mentions the `AFX_MANAGE_STATE` macro but my exported functions already use that and execution doesn't get that far in any case. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Could you add the callstack at the point, where the debug assertion fails?

Comment: @IInspectable, I've updated my question to include the call stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to track down the cause of my crash. A library used by my DLL was linking statically to Boost.Thread and causing this issue, presumably due to a runtime mismatch. Changing the library to link dynamically to Boost instead seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: The callstack you provided seems to indicate, that the deadlock occurred while running the global object initializers. It doesn't look like a runtime (I'm assuming you meant C Run-Time) mismatch. Although dynamic linking solves (if you're lucky, or masks if you ain't) several issues.

Comment: I found a very similar issue in customer code :(.   Why did I try to rebuild this?  You touch it, you break it.